# How to login to the website by receiving email/password from the user in requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I can login to website in requests with string in python.
but i want to login by getting data from user

```
import requests

geturl = xxxqweasd.com

postData = {
    'email': 'xxxxsad@gmail.com',
    'password': 'sadsafdsafPass'
}

login = asd.post(getUrl, headers=headers, data=postData)
```

but i want this.

```
email= input("login your email:")
password = input("login your password:")
login = asd.post(getUrl, headers=headers, data=postData)
```

and done.

how can i do this?

edit:

It logs in first, then the 2FA screen comes up. then I want to enter that 2fa code.

first login with strings

then 2fa screen

and then i take 2fa code on email

and I enter the 2fa code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on how [variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp) and specifically [dicts](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) work on w3schools.

```py
email= input("login your email:")
password = input("login your password:")
post_data = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
}
login = asd.post(getUrl, headers=headers, data=post_data)
```

Comment: It logs in first, then the 2FA screen comes up. then I want to enter that 2fa code.

first login with strings

then 2fa screen

and then i take 2fa code on email

and I enter the 2fa code.

Comment: then you need logic to read the email, and enter the 2FA code from that into whatever 2FA site the first POST produces. But that completely depends on how the 2nd page works. You might have to use automation like selenium to be able to do that. But that's quite a bit more complicated than the original question...